# Reciprocal mapping on an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of $z$ under the mapping $w = z^{-1}$ where $|z-1|\leq 1, z\neq 0$.
I know that for equality, it is a circle through the origin, hence, this particular case will map to a line (particularly, the line $u = \frac{1}{2}$.)
However, I'm not sure how to do the rest. I'm imagining infinite concentric circles with radii decreasing to zero with centre $(1,0)$, but I'm not sure if this is correct to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by direct insertion of the transformation. You have the following indentical formulations. Let $w = x + i y$:

$$
|\frac{1}{w} - 1| \leq 1 \\
|w - 1| \leq |w|\\
|w - 1|^2 \leq |w|^2\\
(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 \\
 (x-1)^2 \leq x^2 \\
-2x +1 \leq 0\\
x \geq \frac12
$$

So the image is the halfplane in $w$-space where the real part of $w$ is $\geq \frac12$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to "visually" or "intuitively" think of how it'd get mapped by using my idea? (the one with infinite concentric circles with decreasing radii)

Comment: You could use the geometric picture which you propose. However, upon calculating the conditions  for $|\frac{1}{w} - 1| = r < 1 $ for some radius $r$, this gives a nasty locus trajectory for $w$, so I guess this won't help much.